# use feeder with batch, QPS will be very low, is my script any wrong, tks

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

the csv file is about 47MB, if i do not use `batch`, is will cost to much time to load the file, and QPS can reach 8000+.
[do not use batch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY0Sc.png)

but if i use `batch(10000)` or even more `batch(100000)`, QPS will be very low about 800+. (the file has 100000 records)
[use batch(100000)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65q1i.png)

script like this:

```scala
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.feeder.BatchableFeederBuilder
import io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.protocol.HttpProtocolBuilder

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class SuggestDot extends Simulation {

  val protoal: HttpProtocolBuilder = http.warmUp("https://www.baidu.com")
    .baseUrl("http://192.168.106.142:8080")
    .connectionHeader("keep-alive")
    .check(jsonPath("$.ret").ofType[Int] is 0)
    .check(jsonPath("$.data.data[0]") exists)

  val files: BatchableFeederBuilder[String]#F = csv("suggestDot.csv").batch(100000).circular

  val test: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("lalamap.myhll.cn").forever(
    feed(files).exec(
      http("suggest/doc")
        .get("${url}&isNewVersion=true")
    )
  )

  setUp(
    test.inject(atOnceUsers(100)).protocols(protoal)
  ).maxDuration(60 seconds)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that will be fixed in upcoming Gatling 3.4.0, see https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3943 and https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3944.

BTW, I can see from your screen captures that you've forked Gatling. Please consider being a good open-source citizen and contributing upstream.

Comment: i will try this version later
tks, am still learning about design gatling exts